# Container does not expand status bar area after switching full-screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fully fill the screen, but when I switch to full-screen mode, the container doesn't cover the status bar.

Here is how I switch full-screen view:

```
onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_fullscreen) {
                  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
                  _fullscreen = false;
                } else {
                  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(
                      SystemUiOverlay.values);
                  _fullscreen = true;
                }
              });
            }
```

In [normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2iQS.png), container cover status bar, but in [full-screen view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg1I8.png) it does not. Actually, the screen slides down a bit.

Here is my entire code of body:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: new InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  titleStateSelector();
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: _colorContainer,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Use
 `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` in your `initState()` like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Splash");

    // Start full screen
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  }
```

to start the screen in full-screen mode.

Next use
 `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values)`
in your `dispose()` function to exit full-screen mode for next screens.

```
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // Exit full screen
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution did not solve my problem but I realized that this "sliding down" problem is specific for Pixel 4. When I emulate Pixel 2, the screen does not slide down like Pixel 4 and seems working fine.